# 2D binned scatter plot in d3.js? Rect bins are not drawn from origin?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, scatter-plot, binning

I'm trying to make 2D binned scatter plot in d3.js. The idea is when the user selects number of bins n, we get the nxn matrix of bins colored by number of elements inside. I tried to do it with d3.bin(), but the problem is if we have a different scales on x and y axis and these bins are defined by side value which could be different for x and y axis. How can I fix this code to make it work for 2D binning?

```
var margin = {top: 40, right: 40, bottom: 40, left: 40},
    w = 380 - margin.left - margin.right,
    h = 380 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var color = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 1000])
    .range(["yellow", "darkred"])
    .interpolate(d3.interpolateLab);


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" +margin.left+ "," +margin.top+ ")");
var points = [];
d3.csv("static/data/data_for_density2d.csv", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {     
        d.time = +d.x;
        d.intensity = +d.y;
        points.push([d.time, d.intensity]);   
    });
    function split(left, right, parts) {
    var result = [],
        delta = (right - left) / (parts - 1);
    while (left < right) {
        result.push(left);
        left += delta;
    }
    result.push(right);
    return result;
}
    console.log(split(0, d3.max(data, function(d) {return parseFloat(d.x);}), 10));
    console.log(d3.min(data, function(d) { return parseFloat(d.x); }));
    var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(split(0, d3.max(data, function(d) {return parseFloat(d.x);}), 10))
    .range([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {return parseFloat(d.x);})]);
       console.log(x.domain());
    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return parseFloat(d.y); })])
        .range([h, 0]);

    var yinv = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return parseFloat(d.y); })])
        .range([0, h]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom");
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left");
    console.log(h);
    console.log(parseFloat(h/10));
    var side = 2;
    console.log(w, h);
    var bins = d3.bin()
        .size([d3.max(data, function(d) { return parseFloat(d.x); }), d3.max(data, function(d) { return parseFloat(d.y); })])
        .side(side);
    svg.append("g")       
        .attr("class", "x axis")       
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + h + ")")       
        .call(xAxis);   
    svg.append("g")       
        .attr("class", "y axis")       
        .call(yAxis);
        console.log(x(side));
    svg.selectAll(".square")       
        .data(bins(points))       
        .enter().append("rect")       
        .attr("class", "square")       
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })       
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y)-yinv(side); })          
        .attr("width", x(side))
        .attr("height", yinv(side))
        .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.length); }); });
```

I've tried to adjust the domain by spliting it in 10 parts, where 10 should be number of bins user selected.

UPDATE: I've decided to use d3.rectbin() function based on this example: https://d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/density2d_histogram2d.html
I define sizes of rectangle like this:

```
    var numBin=10;
  // Compute the rectbin
  var size = (d3.max(data, function(d) {return parseFloat(d.x);})-d3.min(data, function(d) {return parseFloat(d.x);}))/numBin;
var sizeY=(d3.max(data, function(d) {return parseFloat(d.y);})-d3.min(data, function(d) {return parseFloat(d.y);}))/numBin;
var rectbinData = d3.rectbin()
    .dx(size)
    .dy(sizeY)
    (inputForRectBinning)
```

But rectangles are not drawn from origin of the scatterplot, how do I fix this so whatever number of bins user selects rectangles are drawn from origin of plot? Example of rects not being drawn from origin:

[image]